# Blender Multiple Animations

Tags: animation, game-engine

I made an animation for my gun in my FPS, but I came across a problem while making another animation. If all the keyframes are saved to the object itself, then I can't make another animation because the previous one is in the way. Is there a way to have more than 1 animation on an object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create multiple animations for a single object. 
There are 2 ways to do it.

Either key frame your animation on time line as mentioned by @Xortrox above , or do some advance working in dopesheet/action editor, which allows you to create multiple animations, all seperate in their own animation set.

I prefer the 2nd option of dope sheet editor, as it gives more flexibility.
[image]
[image]

Comment: A heads up with actions: If they are unused, they will be deleted. Make sure to tick the "Save this datablock even if it has no users" button for them. It is the F next to T-Pose in the screen above.

Comment: thanx for mentioning the Datablock stuff. I forgot to add it.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. One problem, the keyframes from the previous animations are in the way, how do I get them out of the way when I'm working on another animations?

Comment: In Action editor, Select the Poses ( T-Pose, Walk etc) every pose has its own keyframes. 
If not sure, upload your blend, so that we can look at it.

Answer (score -1):

In most game engines I would be basing the animations on several starting frames, that is for example: 
Run animation = frame 0 -> 59 
Idle animation = frame 60 -> 119

Doing a quick google of "Blender Multiple Animations" brought up this as the first link however:

http://eelstork.deviantart.com/art/Multiple-animations-in-the-same-file-Blender-Tut-321883259

Comment: Well, can you be a little more specific? For example add details on the method you use for the game engine, and quote the link's content (with mention to the author)